# Python convertion .xmcd to .mcdx of multiple files in nested folders using API for built-in MathCAD Prime Converter

Tags: python, scripting, converters, mathcad

I have enormous number of .xmcd files needed to be converted to .mcdx.
Inside most of them there are links to each other.
Considering nested structure of my files and the fact that you can not choose the whole folder for nested convertion in built-in MathCAD Prime 5.0.0.0 Converter I need to automate at least filling Converter with list of files.
Would be even better - to make the whole process fully automatic.
Have someone done this before? Is there any API for the Converter? Nothing like that was found by me in the PTC support database :(

There is some kind of workaround - to generate multiple paths to files relative to the root folder and join them with " "`s but resulting string is far too long to be accepted by the FilePickupDialog of the Converter. Too many files needed to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use built-in converter. Though it can not select a folder to convert all nested files, you can just type <*.*mcd> into search box in FilePickupDialog while being inside your root folder. As a result you get a selectallable list of nested files.